# How to convert "Only A and B" into predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

"Only John and Paul live in Model Town and no one else lives there."

How would you convert the upper sentence into predicate logic?

With one person, it seems like we'd write it as:

∃x:(LivesInModelTown(x)∧∀y:(LivesInModelTown(y)⟹x=y))

But I'm confused as to how to write it for 2 people. Thanks.

Comment: You in addition have to introduce constants to denote the two specific persons John and Paul.

Comment: Can you please give me an example as to how to write that in predicate logic? Thanks

Comment: To translate "Only a and b have property P and no one else does": First note the beginning word "only" is redundant since in the rest of it we're told no one else has the property. Then symbolize as "P(a) and P(b) and (for all x) [If P(x) then x=a or x=b]."

Comment: I see @coffeemath thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Haseeb Ali--- you are welcome.